# How do I access class variables in ruby, in the context of making a gem?

Tags: ruby, scope, rubygems

I am trying to learn ruby right now, but I am struggling with the idea of scope. I have put together an incredibly basic git hub search gem, but I really dont know how to access, or just return a single variable.

Here is the main API handler class (/lib/basic_github_search/basic_github_search_api.rb):

```
require 'HTTParty'

module BasicGithubSearch
  class BasicGithubSearchApi
    attr_reader :urls

    def initialize(k)
      keyword = k
      @url = "http://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=#{keyword}&sort=stars&order=desc"
    end

    def search
      response = HTTParty.get(@url, headers: {'User-Agent' => 'BasicGithubSearch_Spider'}, :verify => false)
      response.parsed_response
      @SearchItems = response["items"]
      @urls = []
      @SearchItems.each do |i|
        @urls += [i["html_url"]]
      end
      #puts @urls
    end
  end

  BasicGithubSearchApi.new("tetris").search
  puts @urls
end
```

Specifically, I am wondering how I would access the urls variable in the main module's class?

My main class file (/lib/basic_github_search.rb):

```
require "basic_github_search/version"
require "basic_github_search/basic_github_search_api"

module BasicGithubSearch
  def self.gitSearch(keyword)
    BasicGithubSearchApi.new(keyword).search
    #from here, how would I access the urls variable?
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help you can provide, especially if I am just missing something painfully obvious.

If anyone knows of any simple to follow gems that I can look at, that would be great too, I always find learning from examples help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby, the last result will be returned from the function:

```
def search
  response = HTTParty.get(@url, ...)
  response.parsed_response
  # do not capitalize variables names
  @search_items = response["items"]
  @urls = @search_items.map do |i|
    i["html_url"]
  end
end
```

The last assigned value (`@urls` in this particular case) will be returned.

To use it, just assign a call to method to a variable:

```
module BasicGithubSearch
  def self.gitSearch(keyword)
    result = BasicGithubSearchApi.new(keyword).search
    puts result.inspect # prints the result out
    result # returns the result variable from this method
  end
end
```